# Why does a Rails Application run properly from a port but not from a subdomain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

Here is the content of my /etc/apache2/sites-available/default  file

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName domain.com
         # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to ('public')!
   DocumentRoot /var/www
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName a.domain.com
             # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to ('public')!
   DocumentRoot /home/user/A/public
   <Directory /home/user/A/public>
    AllowOverride all
    Options -MultiViews
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName b.domain.com
             # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to ('public')!
   DocumentRoot /home/user/B/public
   <Directory /home/user/B/public>
    AllowOverride all
    Options -MultiViews
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName c.domain.com
             # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to ('public')!
    DocumentRoot /home/user/C
    <Directory /home/user/C/public>
    AllowOverride all
    Options -MultiViews
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The intention is to "link" the subdomain names (such as a.domain.com) to a Rails application running on a specific port (with multiple low intensity Rails application on the same server).  The configuration shown above works to redirect to the appropriate static page AND/OR rails application, except for one of them which has a problem:

The problematic Rails application runs properly when accessed via:
domain.com:port  (or domain.com:4444 )

however when attempts to access the same Rails application via:
c.domain.com  (subdomain linked to the directory where the Rails app lives)
it throws this error:

```
https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh (at master) is not yet checked out. Run `bundle install` first. (Bundler::GitError)
```

To be clear, the same Rails application WORKS properly when accessed from domain.com:port but fails with c.domain.com

Since one of the Rails applications in the collection works and another fails, I find this very puzzling.  So far I cannot find anything like this in my searches.

Questions and suggestions are very welcome.

Thank you,
~ Allen

NEWS:
I'm still reading documentation in an attempt to understand why accessing the rails application by port or by sub domain (domainname.com:port  .vs.  sub.domainname.com) behaves differently. However, I did determine making apache the owner of the directory structure helped get access by sub domain working. (apache user = www-data )

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /home/user/app
```

resolved the issue for one of the rails apps. There was also a .htaccess file in the public directory which had to be removed and the need to use this version of the bundle command:

```
bundle install --path vendor/bundle
```

that was not needed for the other application running on a sub domain.

It seems I have technically solved the puzzle, however I still don't understand the why it was necessary for one application and not for another.

Answer (score 0):

Are your document roots all symlinks to the same RAILS_ROOT directory? Or is there a copy of the app in each of the document roots?

Comment: each rails application is located in a separate directory structure, thus /home/user/A/public is a different application than /home/user/B/public (and so on...)

Comment: Do you have the net-ssh gem in your Gemfile in the RAILS_ROOT for c.domain.com? If not you'll need to add it and run `bundle install`. If I'm understanding the case correctly, that is -

Comment: the installation of the Rails application works (thus net-ssh gem is present) when it is run from domain.com:port-number (domain.com:5500) and the sub-domain is 'linked' to the very same directory structure so the gem "must" be there.  I'm trying to figure out how the access methods (by port .vs. by subdomain) are different.  Clearly they are different as there is only one installation of the software in one directory, yet one access method works and the other does not.

Comment: In your previous comment, you said that each rails application is in a separate directory structure and is a different application, but in this comment you are saying that all of the subdomains are linked to the same rails root... I'm confused. What does `bundle show net-ssh` show if you are in the rails root for c.domain.com (the domain where the app isn't running)

Comment: bundle show net-ssh shows it to be installed.  there are two ways to access the application  domain.com:5000 (port) and a.domain.com (sub domain).  Both the port and the sub domain attempt to run the same application, they just arrive at the application from different URLs. I admit, I don't know how they "route" differently, but it seems the "path" from the URL to the application directory is in some way different.  I just found a document that might solve the problem: http://blog.phusion.nl/2010/09/21/phusion-passenger-running-multiple-ruby-versions/